# This operation is not supported for a relative URI, error browsing SVC-service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, svc

I get the following error when browsing to a svc-service for a website (browsing it at the server it is located at). The website uses IIS7.

```
This operation is not supported for a relative URI.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: This operation is not supported for a relative URI.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: This operation is not supported for a relative URI.]
   System.Uri.get_Scheme() +8045854
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.FilterBaseAddressList(Uri[] baseAddresses, Uri[] prefixFilters) +142
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +598
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +50
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1172

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: This operation is not supported for a relative URI..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +900192
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +192830
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +107


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Link to the service: [Link](http://www.roros.kommune.no/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc/)

Some of web.config for the site:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <add prefix="http://www.roros.kommune.no/"/>
            <add prefix="www.roros.kommune.no/"/>
            <add prefix="item"/>
            <add prefix="http://www.roros.kommune.no/templates/eDemokrati/Services/"/>
            <add prefix="www.roros.kommune.no/templates/eDemokrati/Services/"/>

        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

What is the error caused by and how do I solve this?

Comment: @Bala R,
Thanks!
Feel free to add your comment as an answer, and I will choose it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception message indicates, relative URI is not allowed. Try removing the `prefix="item"` and make all of them an absolute URI.